# Oracle SQL / PL/SQL: Insert if changed/not found; else do nothing

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-merge

Totally reedited this after some thought. Originally I was hoping to combine with a separate MERGE statement, but forget that. To be clear this is not an upsert. I want to add a new record if an existing, matching record is not found.

Let's say `mytable` holds columns `foo`, `bar`, `baz`. Where (if relevant for performance sake) `foo` and `bar` together uniquely identify the record.

a) If not `foo` and `bar` then insert `foo`, `bar`, `baz`

b) Else, if `foo` and `bar` but `baz<new>` does not equal `baz<old>` insert `foo`, `bar`, `baz<new>`

c) Else if all three match then do nothing

Note that `b` is likewise a new record not an update. Essentially this is a log recording changes to `baz`.

As an added bonus, it would be great if I could get the MERGE statement (to `my_second_table`) to only attempt a merge on `a` and `b` since case `c` means `baz` is unchanged therefore we don't need to touch the other table. But I know you can't have everything.

*Why can't they just use JavaScript like Mongo does...?*

Comment: There is no PL/SQL in your example

Comment: I just figured a PL/SQL procedure what I'd need to the extend this to do what I need it to, no? At least this is the direction googling has led me.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to update two tables in a merge statement, but there are a couple of alternatives. One is adding a trigger to the first table. The trigger will fire on any change you want and can insert rows in the second table:

```
CREATE TRIGGER IUA_Table1
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
ON Table1 FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

  INSERT INTO LogTable(groupid, var, sku_no )
  VALUES(:new.groupid, var, sku_no);

END;
```

This trigger will fire on any insert or update, so not just your merge statement.

Note that some people *love* triggers and use them for most anything, while others are very reluctant to use them for anything. Personally I think you shouldn't put too much business logic in triggers, but for logging changes like this it might be acceptable.